# Can we load different external links if the screen width is too small?

Tags: html, performance

I would like to know if we can load different external ressources (such as jQuery) depending on a screen width, I know we can do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)" href="mobile.css" />
```

but can we do

```
<script media =" screen and (min-device-width: 800px)" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you mean different js libraries

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it works like the css. But it works as follows:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 800) {
    $.getScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js');
}
```